# call jquery function from server

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, events

In **asp.net**, How can i trigger client side jquery event from server. I want to implement it in my chat section... current the chat seems to work fine... but it has one problem... i have to send a request  every 5 seconds from client's browser  to the his chat history.. which i feel is not a good idea...

can anyone provide any solution for my problem

Comment: jQuery is a client side language means, it can only run in the client's browser. there is no way you can call it from server however, you can put inline javascript in your html code and that will be executed when page loads on the client side.

Comment: Actually if you do a Chat based on JQuery then you have to do it by Polling. That means you have to send an ajax request every xxx seconds and ask the server if there are new messages.

Comment: hello ITroubs... this is what i m doin currently... but is it a good idea to send request after every x seconds...

Answer (score 1):

By default you need to do it with polling from the clients browser. That's how ajax works out of the box. There's a technique called **Comet** which is a push model.

You can try to use a jQuery plugin like this: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jQuery-Comet-Push-API.

In the (near) future you could make use of **websockets** as well in HTML5. Here's information taken from http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX11/HTM10.

> WebSockets, an emerging specification
>   being standardized by W3C and IETF,
>   will enable web browsers as well as
>   client applications to open a
>   bi-directional, full-duplex
>   communication channel with a remote
>   host.

Be sure to check out that MIX11 video!

Comment: +1 for web sockets mention.  Additionally, we should probably mention while Comet is often called "push"...push is a misnomer.  Comet is a (optimized) long-polling mechanism, and as such, there is no true subscribed event-driven "push" of data.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the best that you can do without getting into something like HTML5 WebSockets which are not really ready for regular usage yet.

Two options:

- (conservative option) Accept that you will be polling the server and optimize the way you do the polling to keep the impact low.
- (edgy option) Try out some of the new libraries that emulate Websockets.

Answer (score 0):

Although, I am not that skilled in ASP.Net, this problem can be solved in another way.

Have the server return the name of function you need to execute, then call it in the callback function?

Kinda like this (It is just a typo but)

```
$.post("yourpage.aspx",
   {
      d1: "v1"
   },
   function(data) {
     //now the data will hold the name of the function
     window[data](); 
   }
);
```

Now you can wrap the above code, in the another function, and set up a timer, to check for the response regularly, and execute the function if a condition is matched.

<sub>P.S. I have skipped the part, where the scripts check if the condition is matched.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of HTTP.

Thats how the browsers work. Client sends a request to the Server and Server responds. There is no other way (for now) to go the other way. It's simple and that's one of the reasons HTTP protocol was so popular.

But now things are changing and HTML5 support web sockets. If you developing for a HTML5 supporting device (latest versions of all browsers + iPhone/iPad support sockets)  then websockets is the way to go.

On the other side, you can go with Comet polling (as mentioned by XIII). Basically it client sends a request to the server and waits until server has anything to respond to. I am not too sure what is a good way of implementing it in ASP.NET (as I think there is a limit of concurrent connections) but it's a pretty useful technique in Nodejs.

Comment: Duplex usually works when you have two servers collaborating with each other. In a user scenario, we have a browser which cannot respond to requests, it can only make requests and get the response.